# Trying to access the long double Math macros and the precision of long double

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, math.h

First of all I am trying to access these long double macros defined on Math.h.

```
/*  Long-double versions of M_E, etc for convenience on Intel where long-
    double is not the same as double.  Define __MATH_LONG_DOUBLE_CONSTANTS
    to make these constants available.                                        */
#if defined __MATH_LONG_DOUBLE_CONSTANTS
#define M_El        0xa.df85458a2bb4a9bp-2L
#define M_LOG2El    0xb.8aa3b295c17f0bcp-3L
#define M_LOG10El   0xd.e5bd8a937287195p-5L
#define M_LN2l      0xb.17217f7d1cf79acp-4L
#define M_LN10l     0x9.35d8dddaaa8ac17p-2L
#define M_PIl       0xc.90fdaa22168c235p-2L
#define M_PI_2l     0xc.90fdaa22168c235p-3L
#define M_PI_4l     0xc.90fdaa22168c235p-4L
#define M_1_PIl     0xa.2f9836e4e44152ap-5L
#define M_2_PIl     0xa.2f9836e4e44152ap-4L
#define M_2_SQRTPIl 0x9.06eba8214db688dp-3L
#define M_SQRT2l    0xb.504f333f9de6484p-3L
#define M_SQRT1_2l  0xb.504f333f9de6484p-4L
#endif /* defined __MATH_LONG_DOUBLE_CONSTANTS */
```

I have added this to the beginning of my class:

```
#define __MATH_LONG_DOUBLE_CONSTANTS
#import <math.h>
```

Apple says it is necessary to expose the macros, like for example, `M_PIl` (long double PI).

I try to use `M_PIl` and I get this message:

> use of undeclared identifier 'M_PIl', did you mean 'P_PID'?

Apple defines long doubles as being 128 bit numbers on GCC4 and I suspect on LLDB too and they also say these numbers can represent numbers between `3.36210314311209350626 E-4932` and `1.18973149535723176502 E4932`. If my math is not wrong, this is using 1 bit for the mantissa sign, 1 bit for the exponent sign, 16 bits for the exponent, so the mantissa must have 110 bits.

To test this I do

```
long double pi = acosl(-1.0L);
NSLog(@"%.200Lg", pi);
```

This is what is printed on console

```
3.14159265358979323851280895940618620443274267017841339111328125
```

that is 64 characters, counting the point.

Then I try this

```
NSLog(@"%.200Lg", M_PI);
```

and this is printed

```
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

that has 52 characters.

First thing strange is the difference between `M_PI` and the long double version in terms of characters. I was expecting twice the number of characters.

Another thing is that Apple defines M_PI as

```
#define M_PI    3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
```

that is not even remotely close to what is being printed by the last command.

I have also tried to define `PI` manually to 1000 decimal places, just to see what happens...

```
long double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989L;
```

and when I NSLog that to console the result is the same as before...

```
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

again, the number starts to differ from the 16th decimal place...

Also, when I do

```
NSInteger x = sizeof(long double);
```

I obtain `16` (???)

Can you guys explain why these discrepancies and how do I get a long double PI and use the long double versions of the macros defined on Math.h?

Comment: Apple defines `M_PI` that way because I believe it's a `double`, not `long double`...

Comment: I know, this is why they have the long double versions but how do I access them, like `M_PIl`?

Comment: You could probably do `NSLog(@"%.200Lg", M_PIl);` right?

Comment: Nope. Like I said, Xcode whines with `use of undeclared identifier 'M_PIl', did you mean 'P_PID'?`

Comment: I have updated the question with more info

Comment: Strange, when I try it in Xcode I get no warnings or errors at all... Here's the code I used: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e54e1065c4402e6968f3078ba4e7e73a

Comment: I do not understand your code! You are defining M_PIl and the other macros again? Aren't them are already defined on Math.h?

Comment: The redefinition has to do with how the define is handled by the compiler dialect. I know it's strange, but there's a post about it here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-cilk-plus/topic/265759

Comment: please convert this comment to an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: Sure. If you read the post by "Sergey" and the ones after there's more of an explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it boils to down this if I understand correctly regarding `math.h`:

> "There is a 20-digit value value guarded by `#if defined __USE_BSD ||
>   defined __USE_XOPEN`. The constants in those groups are not permitted
>   by the C standard to be defined in strict standard conforming mode.

While the first part of that isn't exactly the same for macOS, the premise is; the second thing mentioned implies the `#define`'s are not able to be accessed based upon the C/C++ dialect used and/or the strict standard conforming mode.

↳ https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-cilk-plus/topic/265759

Including the defines in your `.m` seems to be the solution as discussed in the comments earlier:

```
#define __MATH_LONG_DOUBLE_CONSTANTS
#import <math.h>
/*  Long-double versions of M_E, etc for convenience on Intel where long-
    double is not the same as double.  Define __MATH_LONG_DOUBLE_CONSTANTS
    to make these constants available.                                        */
#if defined __MATH_LONG_DOUBLE_CONSTANTS
#define M_El        0xa.df85458a2bb4a9bp-2L
#define M_LOG2El    0xb.8aa3b295c17f0bcp-3L
#define M_LOG10El   0xd.e5bd8a937287195p-5L
#define M_LN2l      0xb.17217f7d1cf79acp-4L
#define M_LN10l     0x9.35d8dddaaa8ac17p-2L
#define M_PIl       0xc.90fdaa22168c235p-2L
#define M_PI_2l     0xc.90fdaa22168c235p-3L
#define M_PI_4l     0xc.90fdaa22168c235p-4L
#define M_1_PIl     0xa.2f9836e4e44152ap-5L
#define M_2_PIl     0xa.2f9836e4e44152ap-4L
#define M_2_SQRTPIl 0x9.06eba8214db688dp-3L
#define M_SQRT2l    0xb.504f333f9de6484p-3L
#define M_SQRT1_2l  0xb.504f333f9de6484p-4L
#endif /* defined __MATH_LONG_DOUBLE_CONSTANTS */
```

Answer (score 0):

> If my math is not wrong, this is using 1 bit for the mantissa sign, 1 bit for the exponent sign, 16 bits for the exponent, so the mantissa must have 110 bits.

Well your math is fine, your assumption is wrong. Long double tends to be implemented using 16 bytes to accomodate the various different extended precision formats, which include the 128-bit IEEE and the 80-bit Intel.

No need to guess how those 80-bits are used, just [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision).

If you want to use the `#define` constants copy them out of `math.h` and add them to your code protected by a `#ifndef`:

```
#ifndef M_PIl
 ...
#define M_PIl       0xc.90fdaa22168c235p-2L
 ...
#endif
```

Now do your test using `M_PIl` and `acosl()` using the `%LA` hex-fp format so you can see all the bits in hex:

```
long double ld;
ld = acosl(-1.0L);
printf("ld = %LA\n", ld);
ld = M_PIl;
printf("ld = %LA\n", ld);
```

You'll get:

```
ld = 0XC.90FDAA22168C235P-2
ld = 0XC.90FDAA22168C235P-2
```

Both exactly the same as the definition of `M_PIl` with 16 hex digits, 64 bits, in the mantissa.

HTH

Comment: Actually, 16-byte `long double` is not to accommodate any different formats: it's simply to align the values when they are in an array.